# How to regroup or rearrange data to build a stacked bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a dataframe all in one row with multiple columns for values and I need to rearrange them to make a bar graph (preferable using plotly), stacked. The data sample is as follows:

```
Car 1 Fastest Time | Car 1 Slowest Time | Car 1 End Time | Car 2 Fastest Time | Car 2 Slowest Time | Car 2 End Time | Car 3 Fastest Time | Car 3 Slowest Time | Car 3 End Time
```

I would like to rearrange the data and have a bar graph of 3 columns where the Fastest, slowest, and end time are all in one column per Car number.

I tried to regroup the data, split the data but no luck. I am very new to pandas

Comment: can you also include the row of values in your data sample as well?

Comment: Hi Derek, they are just one row in mph, i.e. 55.0, 60, 90, etc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A DataFrame with a single row won't be easy to work with, so you'll want to rearrange things a bit: for simplicity I am going to make your DataFrame long format where every data point is a single row (since you have three cars with three observations each, we will have 9 rows total).

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Car 1 Fastest Time': [55.0],
    'Car 1 Slowest Time': [90.0],
    'Car 1 End Time': [60.0],
    'Car 2 Fastest Time': [60.0],
    'Car 2 Slowest Time': [80.0],
    'Car 2 End Time': [70.0],
    'Car 3 Fastest Time': [70.0],
    'Car 3 Slowest Time': [90.0],
    'Car 3 End Time': [80.0]
})

df_long = df.T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'category', 0: 'Time'})
df_long['TimeCategory'] = df_long['category'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[2]
df_long['Car'] = df_long['category'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[[0,1]].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
```

`df_long` looks like the following:

```
             category  Time TimeCategory    Car
0  Car 1 Fastest Time  55.0      Fastest  Car 1
1  Car 1 Slowest Time  90.0      Slowest  Car 1
2      Car 1 End Time  60.0          End  Car 1
3  Car 2 Fastest Time  60.0      Fastest  Car 2
4  Car 2 Slowest Time  80.0      Slowest  Car 2
5      Car 2 End Time  70.0          End  Car 2
6  Car 3 Fastest Time  70.0      Fastest  Car 3
7  Car 3 Slowest Time  90.0      Slowest  Car 3
8      Car 3 End Time  80.0          End  Car 3
```

We can now use `px.bar` and pass the long format DataFrame as well as the desired values and colors for each category of time (fastest, slowest, end). Plotly also has some useful documentation [here].(https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#bar-charts-with-long-format-data)

```
fig = px.bar(df_long, x='Car', y='Time', color='TimeCategory')
fig.show()
```

[image]